# CoreData/TableView - Ambiguous use of 'subscript'

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

When I try to create a TableView with CoreData data I get this error and don't know how to fix it. I saved the CoreData in another class. I don't know if I even created the TableView right.

```
class listEvents: UITableViewController {

    var logTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectZero, style: .Plain)
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    var eventItems: AnyObject?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var viewFrame = self.view.frame

        viewFrame.origin.y += 20

        viewFrame.size.height -= 20


        logTableView.frame = viewFrame

        self.view.addSubview(logTableView)

        logTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "EventCell")


        logTableView.dataSource = self

        fetchLog()

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return eventItems!.count

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EventCell") as! UITableViewCell!

        let eventItem = eventItems! [indexPath.row] <-- Error here

        cell.textLabel?.text = eventItem.name
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let eventItem = eventItems! [indexPath.row] <-- Error here
        print(eventItem.id)
    }


    func fetchLog() {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Event")


        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)


        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        do{
        if let fetchResults = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [Event] {
            eventItems = fetchResults
        }
        }catch{
        print("ERROR")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this error"? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this declaration:

```
var eventItems: AnyObject?
```

Then later on you do this:

```
let eventItem = eventItems! [indexPath.row]
```

The problem is that you declared `eventItems` as `AnyObject?`, and `AnyObject` does not accept subscripts. It can literally be any object at all, and not every class works with subscripts, so Swift doesn't know what to do.

Since you're assigning `eventItems` as the result of a fetch request, it should be declared as either an `NSArray?` or as something like `[Event]?`. Also, using that `!` after `eventItems` puts you at serious risk of a crash; don't ever use `!` unless you're absolutely sure that you won't accidentally have a nil value.